# Angular 5 / Cordova - iOS constructor not called

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I have made an app with Angular 5 powered by `Cordova`.

So the app work well on browser, android and iOS... expect that on iOS only, after the splash-screen, the authentication guard process, the app did not trigger the constructor or ngOnInit on the login page (or homepage, whatever the first page to display!). Only the html template is rendered. I made my app from the nice starter kit https://github.com/ngx-rocket.

I have checked other similar problem with some workaround using timeout or zone like that:

```
 this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']), { replaceUrl:true });
```

Some people says there is a problem with webpack or the webview. A very complicated issue on that damned iOS !

Comment: Can you link to what some people say about webpack and webview

Comment: I don't remember precisely where, but the idea was the file order on the webpack is not handled well when called with the iOS webview.